# How to receive a dataset in stored procedure?

Tags: c#, ado.net

How can I take dataset as parameter in Store procedure then convert the into table ,which can be used normal table.

**Code :**

```
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@xml", DbType.Xml, sb);//c# code
```

How do I receive this parameter as table in store procedure ?

Comment: as far as i know ! You Can't pass Dataset to StoredProcedure!

Comment: you are saying as "How can I take dataset as parameter" and passing "@XML" in parameter from codebehind? Do you know what you are doing and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a user defined type. Then you can add a parameter to your stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
    @par MYTABLETYPE READONLY
```

In C#, use the following to fill the table value parameter:

```
SqlParameter par = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Display", ...);
par.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Within the stored procedure you can use the parameter like a temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO MyOtherTable
SELECT * FROM @par
```